# How to run android emulator on Ubuntu 20.04 arm64 architecture

Tags: android-emulator, arm64, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to install android emulator on NVidia IGX Orin(arm64 architecture) that has Ubuntu 20.04.

Installed command-line tools with system images for the emulator.
[https://developer.android.com/tools](https://stackoverflow.com)
Had to cross-build the emulator because it was not available for download via the command-line tools with the instructions from here: [https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator#emulator_for_arm64_hosts](https://stackoverflow.com)
When I start the emulator on a virtual device it crashes with the error:

```
*** buffer overflow detected ***: terminated
```

Has anybody managed to get an android emulator working on arm64 architecture or has any idea how to fix this error?